# SQL SERVER PIVOT like PEPSI comes under year then by months etc.. (refer attached image for a clear idea)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I am new to PIVOT... so i dont know whether is it possible or not with pivot.

Here is the table and the sample data i used

```
create table sales_history (brandcode varchar(10) , 
                            syear smallint, 
                            smonth smallint, 
                            salesvalues float )  


insert into sales_history values ('PPS', 2018,1, 256400.00), ('PPS', 2018,2, 278650.00), ('PPS', 2018,3, 236500.00)
insert into sales_history values ('CCL', 2018,1, 356200.00), ('CCL', 2018,2, 365100.00), ('CCL', 2018,3, 174300.00)
insert into sales_history values ('MND', 2018,1, 275200.00), ('MND', 2018,2, 415180.00), ('MND', 2018,3, 274500.00) 
insert into sales_history values ('PPS', 2019,1, 356400.00), ('PPS', 2019,2, 378650.00), ('PPS', 2019,3, 336500.00)
insert into sales_history values ('CCL', 2019,1, 456200.00), ('CCL', 2019,2, 465100.00), ('CCL', 2019,3, 274300.00)
insert into sales_history values ('MND', 2019,1, 375200.00), ('MND', 2019,2, 515180.00), ('MND', 2019,3, 374500.00)
```

-- PRIVOT Query

```
select *
 from (
 select *
  from sales_history
  ) as t1
  pivot 
   (sum (salesvalues) for syear IN ([2018],[2019])) 
  as pivot_brand_sales
```

[image]

using the above query i got an output like in the attached

[please look the attachment for the required output that i was trying and the output i got using the above query ]

Comment: hello murali you got this type of data in SSRS ?

Comment: yes... we require it in reporting itself.

Comment: yes you can do it ssrs with simple query no need to pivot in sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is For SSRS

```
Step 1: Connect DataSource
Step 2: Create DataSet and paste your query in Query Box
Step 3: Click on Insert tab and Click on Matrix and you can put BrandCode into RowGroups
and sYear into ColumnGroups and than Smonth into ColumnGroups and SalesValues Put into Values And Click on Next Button
Step 4: If you dont want to Substotals and Grand Totals uncheck the check box and If you dont want to expand/collapse button on grid than please 
uncheck the checkbox and then click next and finish .
your result will be show as you want.

Regards 
Shehroz
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would use condition aggregation for this:

```
select 
    brandcode,
    sum(case when syear = 2018 and smonth = 1 then salesvalue else 0 end) [2018-01],
    sum(case when syear = 2018 and smonth = 2 then salesvalue else 0 end) [2018-02],
    sum(case when syear = 2018 and smonth = 3 then salesvalue else 0 end) [2018-03],
    sum(case when syear = 2019 and smonth = 1 then salesvalue else 0 end) [2019-01],
    sum(case when syear = 2019 and smonth = 2 then salesvalue else 0 end) [2019-02],
    sum(case when syear = 2019 and smonth = 3 then salesvalue else 0 end) [2019-03]
from sales_history
group by brand_code
```

Comment: I'll always advocate for conditional aggregation/a cross-tab. The `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` operators are so unwieldy when you have anything more than a very simple pivot.

Comment: Yes... we can do this but it generates 6 columns know.. my question is that can i generate it brand and its sales under a year with month split up. If its not possible can we do it by using SSRS right ?